# Pass data to Azure Logic App Request Trigger

Tags: azure

I am a newbie to azure logic app. My aim is to send some variables to logic app(via java service code, which in turn invokes the request trigger with the provided POST URL as REST API) and obtain response as JSON.

Currently i have created a request trigger and the JSON schema looks as follows:-

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "definitions": {},
  "id": "http://example.com/example.json",
  "properties": {
    "CustomerName": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "InvoiceFee": {
      "type": "integer"
    },
    "InvoiceNo": {
      "type": "integer"
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "CustomerName",
    "InvoiceFee",
    "InvoiceNo"
  ],
  "type": "object"
}
```

From the request trigger, i am directing to response action and the following to be returned as JSON response.

```
{
  "CustomerName": @{triggerBody()['CustomerName']},
  "InvoiceFee": @{triggerBody()['InvoiceFee']},
  "InvoiceNo": @{triggerBody()['InvoiceNo']}
}
```

Screenshot below:-

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXO3E.png)

Could you please provide me some reference links of how to access logic app from java service?

I am don't know regarding how to pass the custom created object such that the parameters of the object maps to "CustomerName", "InvoiceNo", "InvoiceFee" properties.

My created java service code is as follows:-

```
InvoiceDTO invoiceDTOObject2 = new InvoiceDTO();

invoiceDTOObject2.setCustomerName("Sakthivel");
invoiceDTOObject2.setInvoiceNo(123);
invoiceDTOObject2.setInvoiceFee(4000);

ResteasyClient client = new ResteasyClientBuilder().build();
ResteasyWebTarget target = client.target("URL TO PROVID").resolveTemplate("properties", invoiceDTOObject2);
Response response = target.request().get();
String jsonResponse = response.readEntity(String.class);

System.out.println("JSON Reponse "+jsonResponse);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code

```
Response response = target.request().get();
```

You are doing a GET-operation. Your Logic App HTTP Trigger would require you to perform a POST-operation using your InvoiceDTO-entity as body (serialized as JSON).

So should look something like this:

```
Response response = target.request().post( InvoiceDTO.entity(invoiceDTOObject2, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
```

Not sure if it's 100% correct, my java is a little rusty, but that's the general idea.